# Attachment added through hook_mail_alter() is making no effect

Tags: webforms, emails

I'm trying to add one pdf attachment to the mail sent on webform submission. I'm using `hook_mail_alter()` to add attachments to the mail.

This is the code I am using.

function webfpdf_mail_alter(&$message) {
$attach = genpdf($message['params']['message']);
$message['params']['attachments'][] = $attach;
dpm($message);
return $message;
}

The output message shown by `dpm()` shows attachment, but the email doesn't contain attachments.

This is the output of `dpm()`.

```
attachments (Array, 1 element)
0 (String, 568525 characters ) Content-Type: application/pdf; name="Webform-...
Content-Type: application/pdf;
 name="Webform-submission.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename="Webform-submission.pdf"

cSA4NS4wNCAwIDAgMzMuNzMgMjguM......
..../****base64data*****/.....
..... ;
body (Array, 1 element)
headers (Array, 7 elements)
MIME-Version (String, 3 characters ) 1.0
Content-Type (String, 24 characters ) text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding (String, 4 characters ) 8Bit
X-Mailer (String, 27 characters ) Drupal Webform (PHP/5.3.29)
Return-Path (String, 35 characters ) enquires@xxxxxxx.org
Sender (String, 35 characters ) enquires@xxxxxxx.org
From (String, 28 characters ) "LESS" <support@xxxxxx.com>
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not already using it, I think you need [MIME Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) or something similar to handle attachments, and when you do, your attachment needs to be added as an array of arrays rather than an array.
This is what the [README](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/mimemail/-/blob/7.x-1.x/README.txt) file says.

> You can use the following optional parameters to build the e-mail:
>
> - 'plain': Boolean, whether to send messages in plaintext-only (optional, default is FALSE).
> - 'plaintext': Plaintext portion of a multipart e-mail (optional).
> - 'attachments': **Array of arrays** with the path or content, name and MIME type of the file (optional).
> - 'headers': A keyed array with headers (optional).